# Request timeout while uploading movie to app service

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, vue.js

I am having trouble uploading a big movie on to the Azure app service which I created. I get request timeout after 4-5 mins while uploading the movie (greater than 150MB). For the frontend, I am using VueJS and send multiple files by doing promisify all settled function. Don't have any issues while using it locally. For backend, I am using Nodejs(fastify) with a multer package and I am using an in-memory storage option. Once I receive the file basically I upload it to Azure blob storage.

Do I have to send movie data in chunks from the frontend to backend? how to achieve it when I have multiple files.

Can we use socket io?

I tried using socket io. however, my browser freezes if I send a big file and I am totally new to sockets.

I am not sure how can I fix this issue. It would be great if someone can guide me and show me an example.

Looking forward to hearing from you guys

thanks,
meet

Comment: What if you use Axios for this? It has timeout which you can set.

Comment: what do you mean by uploading to app service?

Comment: azure app service mate

Answer (score 0):

Problems for uploading files to server

1. Check the timeout in your axios request (front end) - because you have to wait until the all files uploaded to server (https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance).
2. Check the domain hosting configuration (if you are hosting your backend service in nginx - check the upload limit (https://www.tecmint.com/limit-file-upload-size-in-nginx/))